# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not pushing new view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm having a problem with didSelectRowAtIndexPath I know there are other queries on this point but none seem to solve my problem. Basically the tableview loads but it does't do anything when a cell is clicked, i.e it doesn;t push the new xib. Any help would be great.

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize TableViewControl;
@synthesize tableList;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"The Bird Watching App";
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    tableList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Map",@"My Profile",@"Bird Info", nil];



    TableViewControl.dataSource = self;
    TableViewControl.delegate = self;

}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if ([[ tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Map"])
    {
        Map *map = [[Map alloc] initWithNibName:@"Map" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:map animated:YES];

    }

    else if ([[ tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"My Profile"])
    {
        MyProfile *myprofile = [[MyProfile alloc] initWithNibName:@"My Profile" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:myprofile animated:YES];
    }

    else if ([[ tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Bird Info"])
    {
        BirdInfo *birdinfo = [[BirdInfo alloc] initWithNibName:@"Bird Info" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:birdinfo animated:YES];
    }

 }    


@end
```

Answer (score 2):

The `isEqual:` method on `NSString` performs pointer comparison and not comparison between the actual contents of the string. Your if statements need to use `isEqualToString:` to make the proper comparison.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if ([[ tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Map"])
    {
        Map *map = [[Map alloc] initWithNibName:@"Map" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:map animated:YES];

    }

    else if ([[ tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"My Profile"])
    {
        MyProfile *myprofile = [[MyProfile alloc] initWithNibName:@"My Profile" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:myprofile animated:YES];
    }

    else if ([[ tableList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Bird Info"])
    {
        BirdInfo *birdinfo = [[BirdInfo alloc] initWithNibName:@"Bird Info" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:birdinfo animated:YES];
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Mark. Just tried that but still the same problem :(

Comment: Can you confirm that `self.navigationController` isn't nil?

Comment: I copied what you posted so all the self.navigationController are followed by pushViewController..

Comment: I'm very new to ios development so I am sorry if you meant something else

Comment: That's okay. In this case `self.navigationController` points to the `UINavigationController` object that holds this current view controller and allows you to "push" on a new view controller. If this property is nil, then no navigation controller exists and asking it push a new view controller will do nothing. Add `NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);` to `-viewDidLoad` and see what it logs. If it's nil, we have our culprit.

Comment: I decided to start this project again using a storyboard. Thanks for your help it was really useful.